# ImportError: No module named encodings when installing with pip / easy_install

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I tried installing importchecker with pip and with easy_install:

```
sudo easy_install importchecker
sudo pip install importchecker
```

And i get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in 
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 4, in 
    import locale
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 13, in 
    import encodings
ImportError: No module named encodings

I tried this, but it didn't work either:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local/lib/python2.7
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

Most of the answers I've found refer to this, is there any solution?

Comment: How did you install python? I had the same error while installed Python from sources and 'make install' was done not in proper way.
When I re run python build - I got the success
Above error means Python interpreter could not locate it's pakages in some predefined dir.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `sudo` when install python packages.